# Why do custom User Event listeners stop event propagation?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm attempting to hook into the Friends of Symfony User Bundle events with a custom event listener.  There are many examples of creating a event listener for the FOS User Bundle and I've had no trouble creating the listener, receiving the event and executing my custom code.  I am listening for the FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED event and sending out some notification emails regarding the newly confirmed user.

But there is one problem with my approach.  Namely:

Without my event listener the user is logged in and redirected to their profile page after they visit the confirmation page. However the presence of my event listener stops the normal event propagation, and the user is not logged in or redirected away from the confirmation page.

Is this expected behavior?  I see contradictory information in the documentation.

The FOS User Bundle Docs are ambiguous on the point.  Although they seem to imply from the code example [here](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/controller_events.html) that custom events stop normal propagation, or at least replace the normal action for a given event.

While the Symfony Event documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html#stopping-event-flow-propagation) describes the stopPropagation function that exists for the purpose of blocking event propagation, but only when necessary.

So Do User Bundle custom event listeners block propagation to the normal event that comes built in?  If yes, is there anyway around this?  So custom code that does not need to modify the request or response can simply listen for the event and not affect the normal actions that come with the User Bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question:

FOS User Bundle custom event listeners have no effect on the ones that come with the bundle.  They will all be processed and run as you would expect from reading the symfony docs.

It is worth noting that the User Bundle documentation I referenced above is a little hand-wavy about what the custom event is supposed to be used for.  If you examine the controller code in the user bundle that is dispatching each of the [events](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/FOSUserEvents.php) - after the "pre-action" events are dispatched, and event listeners are processed (including any custom ones you register), the controller examines the event object extracting specific properties that control how the action is complete.  In the [example given in the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/controller_events.html) the custom listener for the RESETTING_RESET_SUCCESS event is using `event->setResponse`.  Here is the relevant section of code from the resetAction in the ResettingController:

```
$dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::RESETTING_RESET_SUCCESS, $event);

$userManager->updateUser($user);

if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
    $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate('fos_user_profile_show');
    $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
}

$dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::RESETTING_RESET_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

return $response;
```

The only thing a custom listener can do to effect the built in controller action, is to pass a RedirectResponse object back in the event, which the controller will then use as the return value for the action - redirecting end users to your chosen URL.

So the final mystery is why my custom event listener on the REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED event broke automatic login after the email confirmation link was visited.  The root cause of that problem was a nasty race condition bug in Symfony itself.  The bug was fixed late last year but I am working on a client's application and they are still running an older version of symfony that has the bug.  In short, sending an email with swiftmailer, *and* spooling the email to memory, could cause a race where the HTTP response is returned before the session file is written out.  A subsequent redirect to the client would result in them loading the older - non-logged in - session file, giving the appearance of not being logged in for that next page load.

I'll post the details about the bugs in a second answer since stack overflow is apparently afraid of too many links in one answer.

Answer (score 0):

The symfony bug mentioned in my previous answer has been fixed in 2.3.22, 2.5.7 and 2.6 and up.  If you are curious here are the github issues that deal with it:

The bug report: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/6417

The fix:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/12341

If you are unable to upgrade symfony to a fixed version, the workaround is to stop swiftmailer from spooling to memory (i.e. send immediately, before a response is returned to the browser).  Comment out this line in your swiftmailer configuration:

```
#    spool:     { type: memory }
```